# Customising the browse for folder dialog to show the path

Tags: c#, winforms

What is the simplest way to customise the `System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog` so a path can be entered using text in a textbox below the tree? This would make it easier to select unmapped UNC paths.

Looks like [this KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306285) has some supporting information.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Just this weekend I needed this.  I looked and looked but could not find it.  Resorted to writing it myself, based on that KB article, and some other things.  Here ya go.  [FolderBrowserDialogEx (article in archive)](http://web.archive.org/web/20090223114903/http://www.codeplex.com/DotNetZip/)

Full Source code. Free.  MS-Public license.

[image: FolderBrowserDialogEx]

Code to use it:

```
     var dlg1 = new Ionic.Utils.FolderBrowserDialogEx();
     dlg1.Description = "Select a folder to extract to:";
     dlg1.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
     dlg1.ShowEditBox = true;
     //dlg1.NewStyle = false;
     dlg1.SelectedPath = txtExtractDirectory.Text;
     dlg1.ShowFullPathInEditBox = true;
     dlg1.RootFolder = System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
     
     // Show the FolderBrowserDialog.
     DialogResult result = dlg1.ShowDialog();
     if (result == DialogResult.OK)
     {
         txtExtractDirectory.Text = dlg1.SelectedPath;
     }
```

Capabilities:  shows editbox, shows full path in edit box.  Can be used to browse printers or computers, as well as files+folders, or just folders.

**Edit, 2018-05-31:**
If the Codeplex link above does not work for you, [this Git resource](https://github.com/jkells/folder-browser-dialog-example/blob/master/FolderBrowserDialogEx.cs) also exists.

**Edit, 2022-02-11:**
There is probably new repo of original author https://github.com/DinoChiesa/DotNetZip/blob/master/Zip/Resources/FolderBrowserDialogEx.cs

Comment: +1 I ended up doing the same ... http://code.google.com/p/videobrowser/source/browse/trunk/MediaBrowserConfig/FolderBrowser.cs

Comment: These are the droids you are looking for: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/518103/bffm-setselection-does-not-work-with-shbrowseforfolder-on-windows-7 This is the reason many of these threads about FolderBrowserDialog exist. For people having this problem, the Shell dialog wrapper control above suffers from the same issue.

Comment: All links above are either broken or point to useless pages. Anybody got an updated link that gets what Cheeso posted?

Comment: Still no working link. Please paste the code in the answer.

Comment: @SteeveDroz - I added a link to a version that works for me.

Comment: There is a bug in the code on GitHub; due to _hwndEdit not being initialized it's impossible to see the full path in the edit box, even if that option is true. To fix it move the line `_hwndEdit = PInvoke.User32.FindWindowEx(new HandleRef(null, hwnd), IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", null);` to the top of the `BrowseForFolderMessages.BFFM_INITIALIZED`case so it's always called.

Answer (score 3):

Try under code project [folder browser](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/selection/folderbrowser.aspx?msg=1050735#xx1050735xx) - this allows customizing the dialog in many ways.

Also in [social.msdn.microsoft.com](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/b16246c7-c2a9-4b37-b0aa-85b1ab4bfb0f) there is a post that suggest creating a form of your own for that and even suggest the code for it.