# Set FolderBrowserDialog to show directly the set filepath folder

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, folderbrowserdialog

The FolderBrowserDialog opens the directory tree to the folder set as folderpath and that folder is selected (marked/surrounded) but the view in the FolderBrowserDialog is at the top of the directory tree and I have to scroll down to the selected folder.

I looked in the properties of the FolderBrowserDialog tool if I could set it to centralize the view to the selected folder, but I couldn't find anything.

But I am sure this is possible, I just don't know how to make it. Can someone give me a step-guide if it has to be set from Properties or a sample code?

**UPDATE:** I used the code from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942150/why-folderbrowserdialog-dialog-does-not-scroll-to-selected-folder) and it worked!

Comment: Can you close this question, if you have the answer?

Comment: @shahkalpesh - Is deleting it gonna close it? Because when I hover `delete` it shows that I will only vote for deleting it. If not - how do I close a question? I haven't done it before. Thanks.