# FolderBrowserDialog with 'Default' button C#

Tags: c#-4.0, folderbrowserdialog

I have tried this solution and it works beautifully [FolderBrowserDialogEx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15440926/2459982)
but now I have to add another button which will be placed next to editbox and upon clicking will show a particular folder always. I have tried this so far.

In the constructor:

```
btnDefault = new Button();
btnDefault.Text = "Default";
btnDefault.Enabled = true;
btnDefault.Click +=new EventHandler(btnDefault_Click);
```

on click

```
private void btnDefault_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    _selectedPath = @"C:\ProgramData";
}
```

How do I add new Button? Full code is available [HERE](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/29499#432677)

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Quote from the link: "First, we need to realize that the Folder Browser dialog is not a .NET control, but is rather the Common Dialog and is part of Windows".  You can't add a button.

Comment: @HansPassant, then does it mean the EditBox which is shown(to show the selected path) is inbuilt too?

Comment: That one is built into the Windows dialog.