# FolderBrowserDialog on company network to select subfolder

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, network-programming, folderbrowserdialog

In my WPF app the user needs to select a folder, which path is in the company network. I use the `System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog` and the following code gets executed on a button click event:

```
        FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        fbd.SelectedPath = "\\\\company.net\\data\\_Confidential";
        DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();
```

[image: FolderBrowserDialog on start]

When the `FolderBrowserDialog` opens, the system automatically scans for other network devices and that causes the following problem:

[image: FolderBrowserDialog after 3 seconds]

The network tree gets filled with other devices and causes my `SelectedPath` to scroll away. This is pretty annoying when a user starts searching for a special subfolder, because he has to scroll down or his selection clicks can hit a newly added device (lost focus).

How can i avoid this problem?

Thoughts:

- Can I extend/overwrite the `System.Environment.SpecialFolder` Enum and 
  set `fbd.RootFolder = System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MySepcialNetworkPath;`
- Should I access the network folder with another dialog/control?
- Should I remove the "Browse..." `Button` in my View and instead scan the whole `\\\\company.net\\data\\_Confidential` path and provide a combobox/other selection control(e.g. own subfolder-tree)?

Comment: you could filter the network tree by searching in that list for the wanted name.

Comment: Is it necessary to use `System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog`? Why don'y you use simple `OpenFileDialog`? http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/dialogs/the-openfiledialog/

Comment: @StepUp `FolderBrowserDialog` because i have to get the name of the folder and than set the `InitialDirectory` of the next `Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog` to the selected folder. Furthermore can the `OpenFileDialog` be used with empty folders?

Answer (score 0):

The FolderBrowserDialog is 'adopting' your PC settings depending on how your Network Discovery is configured on your PC/network. By doing so your folder browsing experience will be consistent over other applications.

Although what you see is default behavior of the FolderBrowserDialog, you may also look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15440926/5793786 Solved an issue somewhat similar to yours @Frank

Answer (score 0):

While I was searching for the same problem I came across this thread:

[How to use OpenFileDialog to select a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624298/how-to-use-openfiledialog-to-select-a-folder)

Where the user uses a "CommonOpenFileDialog" available in the Nuget Package "WindowsAPICodePack-Shell".

This solved my issue, though it uses the OpenFileDialog interface.

Then the network drive can just be browsed.