# FolderBrowserDialog is not supporting the scrollbar for the selected folder

Tags: c#, .net, folderbrowserdialog

#when I give the selected path it is just highlighting the path but not scrolling down to the selected folder

```
private void SetPathClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            
            var directoryDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            directoryDialog.SelectedPath = "D:\\Project\\Test1\\Sample";
            var path = directoryDialog.SelectedPath;
            if (result != DialogResult.OK) return;
            
           
        }
```

Comment: `FolderBrowserDialog` is Winforms, not WPF (though you can use it from an WPF application, of course). Please correct the tags.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why FolderBrowserDialog dialog does not scroll to selected folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942150/why-folderbrowserdialog-dialog-does-not-scroll-to-selected-folder)

Comment: Hi @KlausGütter 
I tried with the above mentioned links still not able to get the proper solution

I tried with the below code but its working only after the second use of the dialog
Can you please help me in resolving this issue


`folderBrowserDialog1.Reset();  
folderBrowserDialog1.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = WorkingFolder;`