# Unable to Open folder in asp .net website

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a fresher and working on a web application using ASP.Net C# 4.5, VS 2012.
I want to open "ixo-global" folder at another server \10.23.23.23\ixo-global\ (Just this folder). I did this using following code:

**Code 1**

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(FolderPath);
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

**Code 2**

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
{
FileName = FolderPath,
UseShellExecute = true,
Verb = "open"
});
```

Each works when I ran this code on Localhost. But after publishing this on IIS, it does not open folder at Client's browser. This may be due to security measure.
I am able to access this folder using Run on server where IIS is installed.
I referred [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624298/how-to-use-openfiledialog-to-select-a-folder), code runs but folder does not open at client browser.

What can I do?
TIA.

Comment: What is the end goal?  Why does the client need to browse the server's files?

Comment: yes. It's a folder on shared path. Right now all permissions are granted to this folder

Comment: But what is the user supposed to _do_ once the folder is open?  Add a file?  Delete all the files?  Pick one and open it?

Comment: sorry for incomplete info in earlier comment. We have a specification file (pdf) for each product. Each Product will have their respective folder with their respective specs file int it. Folder name is equal to Product Code. User can open folder and read file for any Product listed in GridView

Comment: any solution ? or free third party tool worth giving a shot ?

Answer (score 1):

You are starting a process *on the server*, not on the browser's desktop.  When you run it locally, *you are the server*, so you see the explorer window open. When you publish to a different server, explorer opens on the server, so you can't see it.

There's not a way to open up an explorer window to view files on the server unless the client has:

- A direct path to the folder (e.g. via a file share)
- permission to access the folder.

You might also look at third-party controls that let you "browse" the server' files in a explorer-like window, or if the client *does* have access to the folder directly (meaning if the client could browse to the folder in explorer) then you could put the path to the folder in a `file://` link and display *that* in the client's browser.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked if the folder has read rights only?

Comment: yes. It has rights. I am able to create new file in specified folder

Comment: Use an Iframe to request the file from the server. You can create one using JavaScript and make its src the server endpoint.

Comment: I have a link button. On clicking it, can I open this folder using IFrame? Can you share code?

Answer (score 0):

"System.Diagnostics.Process.Start" don´t work on web context, only work in desktop applications.

Comment: Yea. I understood that in hard way! :( Is there any solution ?