# How to choose a folder without opening it with OpenFileDialog C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer, openfiledialog

I have to create a button with which the user has to choose a folder.
I've try with OpenFileDialog, But there I can not select the folder and the folder just open.

This is my code:

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            OpenFileDialog fdlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            fdlg.Title = "C# Corner Open File Dialog";
            fdlg.InitialDirectory = @"D:\dosfiles\ValPoch";
            fdlg.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            fdlg.FilterIndex = 2;
            fdlg.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (fdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                label2.Text = fdlg.FileName;
                label2.Show();
            }
```

I try with this code, He works perfectly, But I not like the window, who opened, Is too small.

```
using (FolderBrowserDialog dlg = new FolderBrowserDialog())
            {
                dlg.Description = "Select a folder";
                dlg.SelectedPath = @"D:\dosfiles\ValPoch\";
                if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    label2.Text = dlg.SelectedPath;
                    label2.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    label2.Show();
                }
            }
```

How can I fix my code with OpenFileDIalog to select a folder not to open that folder ?

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624298/how-to-use-openfiledialog-to-select-a-folder

Comment: I not want to open this small windows for choose to folder.
My second code when I postet is the same, but the window who opened to choose the folder is too small and is different than my first code.

Comment: OpenFileDialog and FolderBrowseDialog have different windows..

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what *you mean* by distinguishing between "opening a folder" and "selecting a folder"?

Comment: Please take a look to the second answer in the link I pasted before. I think this is what you want rigth?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Ookii.Dialogs](http://www.ookii.org/software/dialogs/), a great library in order to use common Windows dialogs including file dialogs.