# How can i make the user to choose file location in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, excel

I have this code which is to export data from datatable in excel, and what i want to do instead to write the location myself in the @"", i want to make the user to choose the location by himself, thanks.

```
DataTable dt = hpl.SearchUserGroup(Convert.ToInt32(txtSearch.Text));
Workbook book = new Workbook();                
Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets[0];               
sheet.InsertDataTable(dt, true, 1, 1);
book.SaveToFile(@"", ExcelVersion.Version97to2003);
```

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624298/how-to-use-openfiledialog-to-select-a-folder

Comment: Asp.Net? WPF? Winforms? Console?

Comment: @Jaxi I tried that, but i get this error "Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it. This exception is only raised if a debugger is attached to the process." i don't know why

Comment: @DarkoArnaudov Since a UI (often) requires a single main thread, your application must behave in a specific way ; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127188/could-you-explain-sta-and-mta

Answer (score 0):

You might need something like below.
I didn't get a chance to test this in Visual Studio

```
string folderPath = string.Empty;  

DataTable dt = hpl.SearchUserGroup(Convert.ToInt32(txtSearch.Text));
Workbook book = new Workbook();                
Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets[0];               
sheet.InsertDataTable(dt, true, 1, 1);

using(var folderLoc = new FolderBrowserDialog())
{
    DialogResult dlgResult = folderLoc.ShowDialog();

    if (dlgResult == DialogResult.OK )
    {
        folderPath = folderLoc.SelectedPath;        
    }
}
//create a temp file with .xls extension
folderPath += Path.GetTempFileName().Replace(".tmp", ".xls");

book.SaveToFile(folderPath, ExcelVersion.Version97to2003);
```

Please let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: what is fbd stands for? cause is showing me error on that word?

Comment: "Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it. This exception is only raised if a debugger is attached to the process." This  error is showing me on this line  DialogResult dlgResult = folderLoc.ShowDialog();

Comment: Are you developing a desktop application or Console application?.

Comment: Desktop Application

Comment: I presume you are developing windows application.  Add the STA thread attribute before your main method. [STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
}

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/2411f889-8e30-4a6d-9e28-8a46e66c0fdb/current-thread-must-be-set-to-single-thread-apartment-sta-mode-before-ole?forum=clr

Comment: nop..[STAThread] should be above your Main method in program.cs file

Comment: but i dont have any main method, first is page load then are all events, im working on asp.net

Comment: Are you sure you are developing a windows application?. Can you find any program.cs file in your project directory?.

Comment: Yes im sure, in asp.net

Comment: Sorry my friend.. you really need to understand the difference between Windows applications and web applications. Asp.net is used to develop web applications not windows/desktop applications

Comment: What i need to do to solve this problem in web applications?