# Find file with Name and Extension

Tags: c#, directory, getfiles

I want to find a file that has .pdf extension and I want to find with name too. For example I have filename = "Work.pdf". I want to write a method that
could find with name. Is there any builtin method for this?

```
string fileName = "Work.pdf"
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\Files", "*.pdf");
// string myWorkPdfFile = files.Where() //search the files with fileName
```

Comment: `string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\Files", "Work.pdf");`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I want to make it dynamic, where i can pick files from particular `fileName`

Comment: `OpenFileDialog` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624298/how-to-use-openfiledialog-to-select-a-folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to pass `fileName` value be second parameter.

```
string fileName = "Work.pdf";
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Files", fileName);
```

Comment: Shouldnt `fileName` not be `*Work.pdf` - or anything with a wildcard since your code is basically only searching for `C:\Files\Work.pdf` and this one only - so he could just simply do `var file = @"C:\Files\Work.pdf"` without "searching" it with `Directory.GetFiles()`