# How to allow user choose save location but not filename with dialog box C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I've made a tax calculator (all theoretical for practise) and it has a function whereby the user can press a button to export a basic PDF tax report. There are slightly different requirements to the tax report depending on whether or not it is an employee or a contractor. Contractors are denoted by having a EmployeeID start with a "C". **So far all good**.

Now I have a requirement for only contractors that the **contractor PDF is saved with a specific name "ContractorTax"**. **Is there a way to have a safe file dialog that only lets users select a location while having a locked file name (and I guess file extension).**

This is the relevant code I have so far:

```
   //Creates PDF.
        private void CreatePdf()
        {           
            //sets default options for save file
            saveFileDialog1.FileName = "Tax Report for " + txtFirstName.Text + " " + txtSurname.Text;
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "PDF files (*.pdf)|*.pdf|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "pdf";
            saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

            /*- create FileStream object (fs) with pdf name, mode type, access type, and if it can be shared 
              - create new document object (A4 page size)
              - create a iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter object, it helps to write the Document to the Specified
                FileStream 
              - open document
              - add paragraph
              - close document*/

            if (txtEmployeeID.Text.ToUpper().StartsWith("C"))
            {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
                Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
                doc.Open();

                doc.Add(new Paragraph("TAX REPORT" + nl + nl + "Employee ID: " + txtEmployeeID.Text.ToUpper() + nl + "Name: " + txtFirstName.Text + " " + txtSurname.Text + nl + "Mobile Number: " + txtMobileNumber.Text + nl +
                        "Email: " + txtEmail.Text + nl + "Department: " + comboBoxDepartment.Text + nl + "Salary: $" + salary.ToString() + nl + "Tax Payable: $" + taxPayable.ToString()));
                doc.Close();

            }
            else
            {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
                Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
                doc.Open();

                doc.Add(new Paragraph("TAX REPORT" + nl + nl + "Employee ID: " + txtEmployeeID.Text.ToUpper() + nl + "Name: " + txtFirstName.Text + " " + txtSurname.Text + nl + "Mobile Number: " + txtMobileNumber.Text + nl +
                        "Department: " + comboBoxDepartment.Text + nl + "Salary: $" + salary.ToString() + nl + "Tax Payable: $" + taxPayable.ToString()));
                doc.Close();
            }



        }
```

I found this question asked before but the answer was only relevant for Java and I'm using visual studio 2017 and coding in C#.

Comment: which framework do you use WPF or WinForms?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11624322/6560579) might be your answer

Comment: WinForms. Thanks @Ackdari that link helped. Seems like I have to use FolderBrowserDialog (which everyone seems to hate but is built into studio). Seems that by installing  Windows API Code Pack 1.1 I can use a much more user friendly and standard CommonOpenFileDialog. I think for this I'll try and keep it simple since there will be no users and try and get the FolderBrowserDialog working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your question, You want the name of the employer's tax receipt to be specified and cannot be changed.

You could try the following code to get it.

```
private void CreatePdf()
    {         
        string path1 = "ContractorTax.pdf";
        if (txtEmployeeID.Text.ToUpper().StartsWith("C")) 
        {

            FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            dialog.ShowDialog();
            string path2 = Path.Combine(dialog.SelectedPath, path1);
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(path2, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
            Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
            doc.Open();

            doc.Add(new Paragraph("TAX REPORT" + nl + nl + "Employee ID: " + txtEmployeeID.Text.ToUpper() + nl + "Name: " + txtFirstName.Text + " " + txtSurname.Text + nl + "Mobile Number: " + txtMobileNumber.Text + nl +
                    "Email: " + txtEmail.Text + nl + "Department: " + comboBoxDepartment.Text + nl + "Salary: $" + salary.ToString() + nl + "Tax Payable: $" + taxPayable.ToString()));
            doc.Close();         
            MessageBox.Show("success");
        }
        else
        {
            saveFileDialog1.FileName = "Tax Report for " + txtFirstName.Text + " " + txtSurname.Text;
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "PDF files (*.pdf)|*.pdf|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "pdf";
            saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
            Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
            doc.Open();

            doc.Add(new Paragraph("TAX REPORT" + nl + nl + "Employee ID: " + txtEmployeeID.Text.ToUpper() + nl + "Name: " + txtFirstName.Text + " " + txtSurname.Text + nl + "Mobile Number: " + txtMobileNumber.Text + nl +
                    "Department: " + comboBoxDepartment.Text + nl + "Salary: $" + salary.ToString() + nl + "Tax Payable: $" + taxPayable.ToString()));
            doc.Close();
        }



    }
```

Hope this could help you.

Comment: Thank you for your time,  that answers my question exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make it simple.

Generally you want the user to select a folder, not a file location.

So you should use `FolderBrowserDialog` instead of using `OpenFileDialog`.
When you get the folder, use `Path.Combine` to combine the file name and the folder name into a complete path.