# Form.ShowDialog Methode

Tags: c#, showdialog

I have created a software, which save some Information in an Excel File. The software has two possibilities:

1. To select the folder and then the software will create an Excel File with random name and there will save the data , or
2. To select an existed Excel File which is created from the user and there will save the data.

How to create a **ONE ShowDialog** to ask the user do you want to choose the folder or the file?!

Code that I have used to choose a Folder:

```
using (var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
           {
               DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

               if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbd.SelectedPath))
               {

                   textBox3.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;

               }
          }
```

Code that I have used to choose a File:

```
OpenFileDialog excelFilename = new OpenFileDialog();

           if (excelFilename.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
           {
               textBox3.Text = excelFilename.FileName;

           }
```

Comment: Ask the user first and then do what you need. Another option is roll your own. IMHO go with the first.

Comment: @Codexer What do you excatly mean with Ask the user!? To make two buttons if the user want one or another Option ?

Comment: You can ask the user how ever you want. You could have a default of choosing a folder, if they don't want to choose a folder, go the file route.

Comment: @Codexer ...but this is not what I asked for !!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use OpenFileDialog to select a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624298/how-to-use-openfiledialog-to-select-a-folder)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this?:

```
MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Ask user what he wants to do", "", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);

string path = null;

//MessageBoxResult.Yes means File, .No means Folder
if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
{
    //File-Picker
    OpenFileDialog filePicker = new OpenFileDialog()
    {
        FileName = "Excel File",
        DefaultExt = ".xls",
        Filter = "Excel Document | *.xls"
    };

    if (filePicker.ShowDialog() == true) 
    {
        path = filePicker.FileName;
    }
}
else if (result == MessageBoxResult.No)
{
    //Folder-Picker
    CommonOpenFileDialog folderPicker = new CommonOpenFileDialog()
    {
        IsFolderPicker = true,
        Multiselect = false
    };

    path = Path.Combine(folderPicker.FileName, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH-mm-ss"));
    
    //Create file in folder
    File.Create(path);
}

if (path != null)
{
    // Do something with path (file user selected/program created)
}
```

Make sure you have the `using System.Windows`, `using Microsoft.Win32;` and `using System.IO;` using's at the beginning of your program.

You also have to add the `WindowsAPICodePack` library to your project to use the folder-picker. You can do that with the NuGet manager. Here's the link to the library: [WindowsAPICodePack - 1.1.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAPICodePack/1.1.1)