# CommonOpenFileDialog does not contain a definition for 'InitialDirectory' and 'Multiselect'

Tags: c#, wpf

I followed Joe's idea on how to use CommonOpenFileDialog to open a folder / file [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624298/how-to-use-openfiledialog-to-select-a-folder/11624322)

I've installed the package `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack-Shell` in my project and included this line as well: `using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs;`

The code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

     CommonOpenFileDialog dialog = new CommonOpenFileDialog();
     dialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Users";
     dialog.IsFolderPicker = true;
     dialog.Multiselect = true;

     if (dialog.ShowDialog() == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
     {

         MessageBox.Show("You selected: " + dialog.FileName);
     }

}
```

However, there are some methods / attributes that I could not use.
I screenshotted the errors I got: [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XthI6.png)

Is there an updated documentation on how to use the CommonOpenFileDialog package so that I can refer to it?

Answer (score 0):

This works, you must simply install it using *`Install NuGet packages`*. Search for  `WindowsAPICodePack-Shell`, then install it for your project.

Next, make sure the `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack` and `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell` DLLs are visible in the dependency list.

Make sure there is `using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs;` declaration in the file where you are using the control.

If you are using it in a console application, add `[STAThread]` right above the `static void Main(string[] args)`.

Answer (score -2):

You could use the [System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) for opening files, it  contains the properties InitialDirectory and Multiselect.

For opening folders, you could use [System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) . With this class, you would need to use the property RootFolder to choose where the browsing starts from.