# How to use IFileDialog COM Interface by P/Invoke in IL2CPP mode of Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, com, pinvoke, il2cpp

I tried to use `OpenFileDialog` in `System.Windows.Forms`, but when I switch the project build type from `Mono` to `IL2CPP`, it doesn't work anymore.
In `IL2CPP` mode i can still use the method by Win32 APIs, but I cannot find a valid solution of *how to use IFileDialog COM Interface by P/Invoke*.
This code doesn't working because the '`IFileDialog`' is not defined:

```cs
[ComImport,Guid("d57c7288-d4ad-4768-be02-9d969532d960"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    interface IFileOpenDialog : IFileDialog
    {
        // Defined on IModalWindow - repeated here due to requirements of COM interop layer
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), PreserveSig]
        int Show([In] IntPtr parent);
// ......
```

Anyway, The API which came from `Comdlg32.dll` is still working, but it has many shortcomings(cannot remember the path of last selected file/folder and so on).
BTW, I want to not only create a File Selection/Save Dialog, but also create a **Folder Selection** Dialog.
Does `IFileDialog` have a switcher to allow me switch the dialog type?
And, how to use `IFileDialog` COM Interface by P/Invoke in `IL2CPP` mode of Unity3D?
I will be appreciated if you could give me some valid solutions.

Comment: I've not tested with Unity, but you can try a similar code to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66187224/403671

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks a lot. I will try it after a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be off the point, but may solve your problem.

`System.Windows.Forms` in Unity `IL2CPP` *does* exactly works but need some changes.

I used the [Unity Standalone File Browser](https://github.com/gkngkc/UnityStandaloneFileBrowser) before, that plugin has a dll file in .Net Framework 2.0. It works in Unity `Mono` Builds, but not in `IL2CPP` builds. In some attempts, I found that just change the `System.Windows.Forms.dll` into a .Net Framework 4.0 or newer one can solve the problem. After some works, `System.Windows.Forms` works fine in my project with Unity `IL2CPP` builds.

Hope I can help you.

Comment: Just change the reference version of ```System.Windows.Forms.dll```? I will try it.

Comment: It cannot be compiled after I add a newer version reference of ```System.Windows.Forms```: ```ArgumentException: The Assembly Mono.WebBrowser is referenced by System.Windows.Forms ('Assets/System.Windows.Forms.dll'). But the dll is not allowed to be included or could not be found.```

Comment: Also try to use newer version of  `Mono.WebBrowser.dll`.

Comment: Still not working... ```NotSupportedException: System.Drawing.Icon::.ctor```

Comment: OK I know. Just change the version of ``System.Windows.Forms.dll`` to 4.0.