# How to add Windows.Forms framework to WPF project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, winforms

I"m a complete noob in Visual Studio.
I'm trying to write a simple app using WPF. I need a dialog that would pick a folder.
I know that WPF doesn't have one, and I need to use Windows.Forms with their FolderBrowserDialog. I need to add Widnows.Forms framework to references so that I could say  `using System.Windows.Forms;` and then just do this dialog. However when I'm trying to follow the instructions, I do not see any Windows.Forms here, except for what's on the image. And even if I add those, it still doesn't take `using System.Windows.Forms;`
What should I do?
[image: This is References MAnager for the project]

Comment: It looks like you built a .Net 5+ Project. Edit the Project file (right-click on the Project's name) 
 and add `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>` -- If you followed instructions related to a .Net Framework Project, you should have seen `References`, not `Dependencies`

Comment: If you have a .Net 6 Project, you can also open up the Project's Properties and tick `Enable Windows Forms for this Project` (it's the same thing as the above)

Comment: @Jimi I think I had long term support  .Net 6

Comment: Then the latter option, less manual labor required (you have to add `using System.Windows.Forms;` *manually* nonetheless).

Comment: As a note, you also have these options: [How do I use OpenFileDialog to select a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11624298/7444103)--  Check [Simon Mourier's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66187224/7444103) first. Also [OpenFileOrFolderDialog](https://github.com/scottwis/OpenFileOrFolderDialog)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First create a .Net6 Wpf project
2. Double-click the project to enter csproj and manually add the following code:

```
<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
```

[image]

3. Manually enter the following new [folderbrowserdialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) code, and then use intellisense to automatically add using System.Windows.Forms; That's it (you can also add it manually)

```
FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
```

[image]

3. call it

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  using FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
  {
    folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog();
  }
}
```

4. You can also go to `Property`->`Application`->`General`->`Windows Forms`->`Enable Windows Forms for this Project` in the .net6 project.

[image]