# Is there an updated version of the FolderBrowserDialog?

Tags: c#, windows, user-interface, dialog, filesystems

Windows seems to utilize in a few places a more modern dialog for browsing and selecting folders (I found this screenshot online, http://media.wiley.com/Lux/97/145397.image1.jpg), so I'm wondering if there's any way to access that dialog and use it in a program myself.

I, of course, know about `System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog`, but that's still using an old TreeView-esque kind of UI that's not really used any more (for good reason, I fear).

I've seen a few of these kinds of questions (for instance, [OpenFileDialog that can select folders?](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/453226-openfiledialog-can-select-folders)) but they're outdated, refer to third-party dialogs (which I'd rather avoid, if possible), or both.

Am I just missing something? I can imagine this sort of thing being hidden in some other library or API/SDK or something. I'm just surprised that Microsoft seems to be using it so thoroughly throughout Windows without releasing it fully, especially since I've seen it at least since Windows 7.

Comment: There is no updated `FolderBrowserDialog`, sadly.

Comment: See if this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576741/customising-the-browse-for-folder-dialog-to-show-the-path

Comment: According to this SO question, the dialogs were updated in .NET 4:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007882/select-folder-dialog-wpf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the Vista version of the OpenFileDialog.  The underlying native interface is COM-based, the [IFileDialog::SetOpions() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761832%28VS.85%29.aspx) was called with the FOS_PICKFOLDERS option.

This feature is not directly exposed in .NET, it has the burden of still having to support old operating systems that don't support the Vista interface.  XP in particular.  If you can afford to no longer support XP, or are willing to write the fallback code that still uses FolderBrowserDialog for old operating systems, then you can find code to interop with IFileOpenDialog in the [Windows API Code Pack library](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack).

Answer (score 0):

THEY DID IT! They finally updated the FolderBrowserDialog look and feel to be consistent with OpenFileDialog and SaveFileDialog! I'm gobsmacked! It's beautiful! I feel like I'm hearing Debussy for the first time. I'm not sure when they implemented the update, but it's there now in WinForms. I want to kiss the dev that finally pushed the update at MS. I spent so much time explaining to higher ups that the tested and trusted MS folder browser was indeed the old style and to write a newer looking one would push the release date. But not more! I love it!

To use the new and updated look and feel for FolderBrowserDialog, simply update to .NET 6.0. I'm not sure if the updated modal popup was added before 6.0, but its there now. And the code seems to be largely forwards compatible. My boilerplate FBD code just works with the new popup.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).